# extend commands in auto completion

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

I'm writing a new auto completion for a make command (called user_make) which should extend parameters to the existing make auto completion.
The problem is that it deletes all the commands which were already initialized there when the make auto complete executed
I can't change the original make auto completion.

I just need to know how can I use the 
COMPREPLY with compgen not to create a new list of commands but only to extend it with new parameters.

Does some one have any idea?

```
#!/bin/sh
# bash completion for ovirt-engine

function _make_auto_completion ()
{
    local cur prev opts
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    #
    #  The basic options we'll complete.
    #
    local cmds
    cmds=`gmake -pn | grep -A1 "^# makefile"| grep -v "^#\|^--" | uniq | awk '/^[A-Za-z]/ {print $1}'`
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$cmds" -- "$cur" ) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _make_auto_completion make
```

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate it with the old value?

Comment: The original make auto completion is another auto completion file which located at /usr/share/bash-completion/completions. I don't know how to concatenate it together I will be happy if you can show me how to do that.
I'm using the following command: COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$cmds" -- "$cur" ) )

Comment: Does `COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -W "$cmds" -- "$cur" ) )` or `COMPYREPLY="$COMPREPLY $( ...compgen here... )"` work for you, or is the `COMPYREPLY` variable empty before you write to it?

Comment: Hi rr, thanks for you comment. it didn't worked for me, I added the code to my question

Answer (score 1):

Yep - I found this question having just added my own extensions to `make` completion - although my approach may not suit your needs.

In my case I'm overriding the completion if the arguments match, then falling back to the normal `make` completion.  So if I do the completion I short-circuit the normal make completion (ie return early):

```
. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make

_my_make ()
{
  local cur prev words cword split=false
  _init_completion -n = || return

  # see if we are in "my" build environment
  if [ -e some-reference.mk ]; then

    # Add your completions here

  fi

  # return now if reply already specified
  [[ $COMPREPLY ]] && return

  # defer to normal make
  _make
}

complete -F _my_make make
```

If you're looking to *extend* the make completion options you could call into `_make` yourself then append to `COMPREPLY`.

A few caveats - since we are using the make completion we start by sourcing the original file to get access to `_make`.  This is not the *correct* way to do this - change the callout to `_make` to look like this:

```
_xfunc make _make  # this way we don't need to source the make completion
```

However - we have problems because we are rewriting the `complete` rule for `make`.  Normally bash-completion does lazy loading of completions - when you try to complete `make` it loads the script called `completions/make`.  This will wipe out our ownership of the `make` completion.  Also if you want to play ball you'd have to replace `completions/make` so that your code can get run instead of the original `make` code.

Instead we source `completions/make` directly and have to add this script to either `/etc/bash_completion.d` or `$(HOME)/.bash_completion`, which avoids the auto loading functionality.

Hope that helps.